# LESS: Access concatenated child of class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

Suppose I've a declaration like this in a .less file that I can't modify (actually it's in Twitter Bootstrap):

```
.nav-pills {
  > li {
    &.active > a,
    &.active > a:hover,
    &.active > a:focus {
      color: #fff;   
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it includes styling for anchors inside a li with the `active` class.

My navigation uses the `current` class for the same purpose in the html markup (and I can't modify the markup either). How can I apply the `active` declaration to my `current` elements by using LESS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just overwrite it in your own stylesheet?

Comment: The "current" class is used in my markup (added clarification) and I can't modify it. An option would be to copy the styling but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using LESS 1.4.0

The latest (currently beta) version of LESS allows you to do this through the `:extend()` function like so:

```
.nav-pills > li.current > a {
  &:extend(.nav-pills > li.active > a);
  &:hover {
    &:extend(.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover);
  }
  &:focus {
    &:extend(.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus);
  }
}
```

Produces this CSS:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus,
.nav-pills > li.current > a,
.nav-pills > li.current > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.current > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really hoped this was possible with less! Unfortunately due to bugs in handling import declarations I can't use 1.4b yet I'll definitely employ this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing somethng but is there a reason why you can't add and compile the following?

```
.nav-pills {
> li {
&.current > a,
&.current > a:hover,
&.current > a:focus {
  color: #fff;   
}
}
}
```

No need to try and change the active code, it just won't get used in your case.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'd like to avoid copying over the styling not to have to maintain the copy in the future. Also the question is about this particular case but there are many such cases for Bootstrap with my html markup.

Comment: What about compiling this into a small, standalone CSS file, then adding a link to this new stylesheet in the head of the web pages, after the Bootstrap CSS files? If this was feasible, there would't be any long-term maintenance.